# how does spring know which connection pool to use?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

How does spring know which connection pool to use?

As is known ,you tell the spring framework a persistence-unit name,and annotate the entity manager with @PersistenceContext,and with Persistence.xml configured.Spring does every thing for you.

I am very confused about the spring annotation "@PersitenceContext" above the entityManager field.
My persistence.xml is as below :

```
<persistence-unit name="hibernate.recommendation_report.jpa">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.113.226:11521:BOSS" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxxx" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxx" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My tomcat server and my webapp work well when and after for a short peoriod of time after the starting up of tomcat server.But hours later,the server reports a sqlexception "Connection already closed".

Is this the problem of misusing db connection pool? How do the spring framework choose a c3p0 or DBCP ? How would I specify the connection pool? Or is the tomcat uses the default DBCP as the connection pool?

Comment: what has spring got to do with this? You present a persistence unit not using ANY connection pool, EXCEPT WHAT THE JPA PROVIDER uses. Your JPA provider is what creates the pool

Comment: Don't spring lookup the persistence.xml and init the datasource for me?I think the JPA provider just manages the entities.I am wandering if I can put some tags/configuration in persistence.xml to specify a connection pool for the framework to use.

Comment: No. The JPA provider looks up the datasource, because that datasource is needed to persist/query the entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can make your tomcat server or other app server provide the JNDI datasource. So that, the your server container's self-contained connection pool can take good care of your the database connection/session.
Tomcat in your case, you specify the JNDI datasource in the $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/context.xml or server.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/sample" auth="Container"
    type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    username=...
    password=...
    url=...
    driverClassName=...
/>
```

the type attribute tells the tomcat which connection pool to use.
By default tomcat6 uses DBCP with **type of "java.sql.DataSource"**.
Make sure to use the JNDI reference in your persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.1" ....>
    <persistence-unit name="hibernate.recommendation_report.jpa">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/sample</non-jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Or use spring xml to config the datasource bean to inject into the your entityManagerFactory.Please [refer to here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-spring-config-connpooling.html).

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:sample"/>
```

See other JNDI resource [attributes available for DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html).
Note: the "java:comp/env/" prefix in persistence.xml data-source is very import.Without it, Spring will not look for the pool provided by your application server to fetch datasource but just use the attribute to construct a simple datasource.
Note: tomcat8 itself provides a even better pool.If you upgrade to tomcat8.

Comment: except that the user did not specify JNDI datasource. He specified a connection URL and driver. So it is the responsibility of the JPA provider, as defined in the JPA spec.

Comment: In the case of only give URL and driver etc, how does the JPA provider ,hibernate for example, manage the connection pool?Would you please show some documentation  from hibernate official?

Comment: I don't use Hibernate. I use DataNucleus JPA. It's documentation for connection pools is shown at http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jpa/datastore_connection.html#Connection_Pooling  Can't see why others won't be doing it the exact same way ... i.e they create a DataSource for the respective pool, and get/close connections as you would in any JDBC usage

Comment: Well,I guess your DataNucleus JPA provider has provided connection pool implementation too.So it can help you do the pool job.